# Background lag in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: unity, compiz, 13.04, desktop-background

I have some lag when i turn off icons from desktop. When I logging i have no wallpaper on background. Instead of wallpaper i have freezed logging screen. And the unity (or maybe compiz) freezes for a while time.  When I turn on icons on desktop all become normal.

https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BIueRP5CYAEJIhH.png

Answer (score 0):

Yea I also have this problem, not sure what has caused it but I'll try to find some explanation. You're not alone!

Edit:

Ok well, do you happen to have nitrogen installed to manage your backgrounds (such as if you wanted a wallpaper for dual screens?) In any case I was using nitrogen and it seems the desktop would freeze because I needed to initialize nitrogen and reset the wallpaper. Basically I just opened terminal and entered $nitrogen & and it worked. I'll go test it some more.

Final Edit:
I just tested this and it works even if I shutdown/log out etc. However, if you don't have nitrogen installed then this probably isn't your problem but this might help someone.